# How to call function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to decode a code and was stuck at the function calling.
The function is defined in the below way.

```js
    Function(){} ({
    
    g: 0,
    
    h :{},
    
    c:{
      a:1,
      b:2,
      d:4
    }
    
    });
```

Please help me how to call the above function. How to display g and to access c defined variables.

Comment: what does "decode a code" mean?

Comment: Please read the syntax of javascript and try again. If problem persists, reformat the question.

Comment: "The function is defined in the below way." — That does not define a function, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really what you want but I will take the following assumptions:

1. Your function declaration are wrong. Check in [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/) how to declare functions on javascript;
2. I suppose that you want to create a function that returns a given object an then working with that;

Based on the guesses above, follows a workable code:

```js
// The correct function declaration. This function returns an object.
function getObject() {
  return  {
      g: 0,
      h :{},
      c:{
        a:1,
        b:2,
        d:4
      } 
  };
}
//The object variable will contain the result of the `getObject()` function
let object = getObject();

//Prints the object to the console
console.log(object);
//Prints the g value to the console
console.log(`g Value: ${object.g}`);
//Prints the c value to the console
console.log(object.c);
//Prints to the console the a value that is inside of the c object
console.log(`a Value inside c: ${object.c.a}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions to my interpretation of your question...

```
function test () {
    return {
        g: 0,
        h: {},
        c: {
            a:1,
            b:2,
            d:4
        }
    }
}

test().g
```

> 0

```
test().c.a
```

> 1

looks like you forgot to name your function and syntax is a bit off...

The only other thing I can think of is you are trying to get a function that is attached to the Window object. If so, you access using window.Function but I don't know why you'd do that.

if this is not what you are looking for let me know. But that's what I got from reading your question.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes @kendall the function is using window object like it is declared in that way

Comment: var B = window[a[1]] ? window[a[1]] : { 1: function() {}}; So it is defined as                                                   B[a[1]] ({ g:0, h: {}, c:{ x:1, y:2,z:3} }); I am not sure how to call this function. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function was supposed to be IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Execution) holding an object which should have been written in the way:

```
(function() {

    {
       g: 0,
       h :{},
       c:{
          a:1,
          b:2,
          d:4
         }
    }
   }())
```